# Eureka always returns url with port 8080

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, netflix-eureka

Port 8080 is always returned from eureka no matter what configuration is in the client. Here is an example of my eureka configuration on the client:

This is the application.yml

```
eureka:
  client:
    register-with-eureka: true
    fetch-registry: false
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://eurekaserver.com/eureka
  instance:
    nonSecurePort: 80
    nonSecurePortEnabled: true
    hostname: myhost
```

The application using the above configuration will try to register with eureka. it can successfully register but eureka returns `http://myhost.com:8080`. The expected url is suppose to be `http://myhost.com`.

The application runs on port 8080 however the restendpoint is reached by `http://myhost.com`. is there any way to fix this?

**--Edit--**

here is my bootstrap.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: myappname
```

Comment: you are not missing `eureka:`? before the `instance:`

Comment: ok, I have added the rest of the configuration

Comment: ok, another question, are you sure that you don't have multiple profiles in your project? maybe your eureka use another config?

Comment: When you say eureka returns 8080, how are you verifying that?

Comment: the eureka web ui has 8080 in the url for every application registered with eureka.

Comment: @ycf_l yes I have verified multiple times it’s using the correct profile

Comment: I think by default `defaultZone: http://eurekaserver.com/eureka` use the port `80` so when you want to register your MS with the same port it makes a conflict? try to use another port instead of `80` or `8080` like that we can make sure that the information is changed correctly

Comment: @YCF_L I have tried starting the application on port 8081. I got the same result.

Comment: In this case your config is not used, can you please show us how you run your api, and the defirent profiles you are using?

Comment: @YCF_L I changed the server port number to 8081. Then eureka returned a url with port 8081. I use eureka with feign client without a base url.

Comment: hmm, sorry no Idea in this case, but I think you have to ping the expert (mister @spencergibb) hope he can help us to solve this problem

Comment: @spencergibb Hi spencer would you have an idea what the solution to this issue is?

Comment: No, I don't. Could you provide a sample app?

Comment: @Luke101 it's up to the administration team to change the host name and the port number, it's up to the front server if you are using one, I have seen this problem many times, but the the admin team solve the problem by giving a new DNS where they hide the port in the DNS

Comment: So to solve your problem search (how to hide the port number in DNS, in the server that you are using)

Answer (score 1):

In which file did you add this config? `bootstrap.yml`, `application.yml`, or a profile specific one? Also check for typos in the properties filename.

So what's happening is that your config isn't loaded properly. The auto-configuration of Eureka Client doesn't find an `EurekaInstanceConfigBean` in the current context, so it's creating one for you.
By default it checks first `server.port`, then `port` and eventually it's setting the port to 8080 if previous keys haven't been set.

I didn't know which version you are using, but this has been the default behaviour for quite some time now.

I hope this helps! :)

Comment: Hi we are using version 2.0.1 and I posted the bootstrap.yml in the question. We want the application to start on port 8080 but when the url is published in eureka it should not use 8080. The app can be accessed without using a port.

Comment: Everything works when using running everything locally. However, when the app is deployed to `dev` it adds a port 8080 to the url which is not desired. The application starts on port 8080 internally but this port should be ignored when registering with eureka.

Answer (score 0):

I'm seeing the exact same behavior. All the clients registered with the server is returned with right url but wrong port number, 8080. I have 2 clients running on the same node with different name and port, the one is really using port 8080 is correctly showed on the eureka server but the one is using port 9090 is somehow also showing port 8080 on eureka server. I have tried to move the server.port to here and there (bootstrap.yml or application.yml) but there's no luck. Any help will be appreiated!

Comment: Did you fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In this case, go to:

1. Run as -> Run configurations
2. Environment
3. Remove the port number 8080 from it and apply
4. Try to run your application with different port by passing `server.port=8081` in *application.properties*

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue and I have solved setting this parameter on application.properties:

```
server.port = 7011
```

It could be redundante (in my case, I get the port from Weblogic) but it is mandatory on Client configuration to avoid to register the service with default port (8080)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have a tomcat dependency in pom.xml. I removed it and it worked. Try removing the `spring-boot-starter-tomcat` dependency from the pom.xml.